# HTML files to a desktop Application?

Tags: html, desktop-application, desktop

me and my team are students and have created a game in HTML5, Javascript and CSS3 which we need for an organization that required the game to be packed into a single desktop application, that can be accessed even if there isn't a network connection.

My question is how to this, how to pack the game?

Comment: If all the files (html, js, css) are on a client machine, it is only a matter of opening your `index.html` in a browser locally. Is your problem of how to package/transfer all the files to a client machine ?

Comment: There are sdks available which will help you to create native desktop application from web app. ex :http://www.tidesdk.org/

Comment: The greatest issue right now is how to create a native desktop app, after a lot of hours of searching I've also found tidesdk and I am currently working on it. Thank you for the suggestion  amrit_neo.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of network connection in order to access this game from clients machines:
In internal network you have to install Web Server like [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/)
and some kind of network connection between clients, it could be [LAN][3]  or [Wireless LAN][4] network.